# How to make batch file continue running when the triggered exe crashes

Tags: exe, batch-file

I have a batch script that triggers an exe (c++ code) with command line input in a loop.

The code for this is something like this:

```
for /f %%j in (file.txt) do (
"MyExe.exe" "input\MyInput_%%j.txt"
)
```

"file.txt" contains list of input file names. The problem is, sometimes my exe crashes for some input files. When it crashes, script stops running and it requires manual intervention.

How can this be corrected so that when ever exe crashes, my script could just display a message and continues executing with next input?

I am running the script on windows XP but a OS free solution would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running it within another instance. Something like this:

```
for /f %%j in (file.txt) do (
    cmd.exe /C "MyExe.exe" "input\MyInput_%%j.txt"
)
```

Comment: :but wont this launch a new cmd prompt for all inputs? If yes, then this will launch many cmd prompts in an instant and will increase a lot of load on my pc.

Comment: Yes it will. But the cmd prompts will be closed and the result of the execution will be returned to the main batch file. Of course you will have to pick up the return value and based on that display an appropriate message. But the bat-file should continue running.

Comment: There is the start command as well but I'm not sure how it works if the execution crashes. http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: i guess, start does the same thing, starts the execution in new cmd prompt. But i would not like to start new cmd prompts as this will degrade the performance of the exe. Cant this be done in same cmd prompt. Something like catching the crash (which i think will be output of the exe) and if the output is ignored, the script can continue. I am not sure if this can be done.

Comment: According to the docs you can use the switch /b to avoid opening new command prompts

Comment: @Garfield The cmd.exe solution will not launch all the instances at once. It will start the first one in a new CMD.EXE shell in the same window. It will not start the 2nd until the 1st finishes. I believe it is the solution you want. Using START _will_ launch all instances in rapid succession and increase the load on your pc unless the /WAIT option is used.

Comment: @dbenham What if my exe crashes? I mean, a new cmd prompt is opened, exe is running and it crashes. Now again manual intervention will be required to abort the execution then only batch file would continue same as in my original problem. The difference will be just that the crash happens in other window than the main window.

Comment: @Garfield ??? The child CMD.EXE will terminate as soon as the exe crashes (or exits), and the parent batch will then launch the next exe via another CMD.EXE. Note - CMD.EXE does not create a new window. It will not look any different than if you had called the exe directly instead of via CMD.EXE.