# Suppress error notification in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch file (my first batch file) that runs a program many times. Unfortunately, the program that is being repeatedly run sometimes crashes with the error "[program] has encountered a problem and needs to close ...etc" (event 1000). This is a problem because in order to proceed I would have to manually click out of the error, and then the loop resumes until another error occurs or the loop is finished.

```
cd C:\Users\username\Desktop\test_file
for %%i in ( 1 2 3 ) do (
    mkdir output%%i
    run_program.command -f envt_file.txt -b instructions.txt -p output%%i
)
cd ..
```

Is there some way to run "run_program.command" and suppress any error messages that may appear?

(I have seen some solutions that may work, but I am afraid to test some of them because I am new at this and still kind of afraid of batch files!)

(I am using Windows 10)

Answer (score 4):

In general, append `>nul` to an instruction to dispose of messages generated, or use `2>nul` (the `2` and `>` must be consecutive to dispose of **error messages**.

Sometimes, error messages are generated as standard messages, so

```
run_program.command -f envt_file.txt -b instructions.txt -p output%%i >nul
```

**should** work if everyone follows the rules

```
run_program.command -f envt_file.txt -b instructions.txt -p output%%i >nul
```

**may** be required

```
run_program.command -f envt_file.txt -b instructions.txt -p output%%i >nul 2>nul
```

Is belt-and-braces.

Really depends on whether you want to dispose of error messages only or all messages.

Comment: Adding `>nul` at the end did not work -- now the program just executes without displaying any text in the cmd shell. The problem is that a Windows dialog box appears displaying the error, so I have to click "Ok" in a separate dialog box to proceed. I found another similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324461/how-to-make-batch-file-continue-running-when-the-triggered-exe-crashes) but I don't understand the solution of opening a separate instance of cmd.exe???

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579394/how-to-avoid-prompt-when-exe-crashes?rq=1) is another instance of this question where I don't understand the proposed solutions.

Comment: Since the executable assumes interactive responses, it's likely that the latter of those solutions would work - have the batch file wait awhile, then terminate it forcefully after a certain amount of time. Really depends on the executable. There's an outside chance that `echo.|executable...` would work, otherwise possibly autohotkey...

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked around so I'm going to answer it here for Internet records. I have the same question and this is the solution given to me. Should work on Windows 10:

1. Open "Group Policy Editor" (gpedit.msc)
2. Find your way to "Computer config" -> "Admin templates" -> "Windows components" -> "Windows error reporting"
3. Enable this settings, "Prevent display of the user interface for critical errors"
4. Optional: enable this one, "Disable windows error reporting" will turn off any error reporting.

What if you want to know if your program has stopped running again? You can do either:

- Open "Event Viewer" to see a log of everything or:
- Open "Control Panel" -> "Security and Maintenance" -> "Maintenance" -> "View reliability history"

Comment: Is it possible to do this from CMD or batch file?